# Obtener un xpath de una busqueda de texto en una tabla

Tags: python, selenium, scraping

Soy nuevo en python, estoy haciendo scraping con selenium.
Consigo llegar a una tabla en donde necesito descargar un pdf, pero solo de la fila que dice "FActura"

La palabra la busco y la encuentro asi:
Driver.find_element("xpath","//p[contains(string(),'Factura')]")

Pero necesito sacar en que Número de row esta ese string.

gracias

Comment: Es que no se cual es el codigo para lo que pregunto justamente.

Comment: Colocar imágenes del código o el código en sí.